# Why is VULKAN_LIBRARY set to VULKAN_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND yet VULKAN_FOUND is TRUE?

Tags: cmake, vulkan

I'm interested in trying out Vulkan for myself, but I'm having difficulty getting CMake to link to it reliably. I decided to use CMake's [FindVulkan module](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/module/FindVulkan.html)... or at least how I think it should work. Here's how I did it:

```
# Hey CMake. Look for Vulkan.
find_package(Vulkan REQUIRED)

# Alright, no errors? Tell me what you found!
message("Vulkan found? " ${VULKAN_FOUND})
message("Alright, where is it? " ${VULKAN_LIBRARY})
message("And I can include it? " ${VULKAN_INCLUDE_DIR})
```

And a little later in the file:

```
# Let's make a library and link vulkan
include_directories(${VULKAN_INCLUDE_DIR})
add_library(myLib myLib.cpp myLib.h)
target_link_libraries(myLib ${VULKAN_LIBRARY})
```

So, I get my results! First off, my CMake output:

```
Vulkan found? TRUE
Alright, where is it? VULKAN_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
And I can include it? C:/VulkanSDK/1.0.65.1/Include
-- Could NOT find Vulkan (missing: VULKAN_LIBRARY)
-- Could NOT find Doxygen (missing: DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE)
-- Using Win32 for window creation
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
VULKAN_LIBRARY (ADVANCED)
    linked by target "TOVE" in directory C:/Users/User/Desktop/TOVE
```

Odd, looks like you found my include directory, but you can't find my library. The messages in the middle are actually GLFW. I kept them in just incase they meant something more. Finally, CMake stops with an error.

Some additional testing reveals that both `${VULKAN_LIBRARIES}` and `${VULKAN_INCLUDE_DIRS}` are blank. As expected, swapping them out with their singular counterparts makes Visual Studio 2017 mountains of confused about my `vulkan/vulkan.h` include.

I can't find any case on the internet where someone gets a `VULKAN_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND`, but there might be another library that has similar issues. Why am I finding only half of the information here? Is it an issue with Vulkan or CMake, or am I just really bad at writing with CMake. I'm relatively new to CMake, and I'm just experimenting with it so I apologize if it was just me misusing some important function or something among those lines.

Comment: 1. Documentation you refers too tells about `Vulkan_LIBRARIES` variable. Hint: variables names are **case-sencitive**. 2. Messages about finding or not finding package's components are printed at the time of `find_package` call. So, the message `-- Could NOT find Vulkan (missing: VULKAN_LIBRARY)` is not from the `find_package()` you show: it is printed **after** your message calls.

Comment: Thanks @Tsyvarev! I had no idea about the case sensitive thing, and I didn't bother trying it because `Vulkan_INCLUDE_DIR` and `Vulkan_LIBRARY` could both be referenced to as `VULKAN_INCLUDE_DIR` and `VULKAN_LIBRARY` and it still contained some information that looked somewhat right. The documentation refers to them as "cached variables" though, so that might be the exception. BTW, I'm pretty sure GLFW threw that `-- Could NOT find Vulkan (missing: VULKAN_LIBRARY)`. I put a message call right after the find_package and it seems to have inserted it before the missing report.

Comment: `This module defines the following variables:` - These variables you may **use** (read) in your code. `The module will also define two cache variables:` - These variables you may **set** for hint the finding script about location of things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same error while trying to compile GLFW 3.2.1 on Windows. The problem is that GLFW CMakeLists uses its own FindVulkan.cmake in "${GLFW_SOURCE_DIR}/CMake/modules" which seems a bit outdated.

Taking some code from the FindVulkan.cmake inside CMake distribution (3.10) to modify the GLFW file works as expected and VULKAN_LIBRARY cache var is filled with the path of the .lib file.

Comment: Yup! However this is fixed in GLFW 3.3. Now we wait for it to come out...